# How to mail, encrypt and send information for use by non-technical users?

Tags: email, encryption

A doctor friend of mine wants to email reports to her patients, but doesn't do so as she only wants it to be viewed by the patient.  Any recommendations?  I am thinking possible solutions might be:

1. **Encrypted E-mail**: Encrypt the email using private/public keys. I think this might be too difficult for the patient recipient.
2. **Encrypted Attachement**: Encrypt the file (not the email) using some software and a phrase for the key, and give the phrase to the patient in person or over the phone. The patient (who most certainly uses Windows or Apple and not Linux) would then, however, need to have access to the software.

   I guess a link to download the software would work, but probably not desirable. Does Windows and Apple have this functionality embedded? Or maybe zip it and encrypt it, or wrap the file in some of executable when clicked will extract it?

Or maybe something else?

Comment: a) simply send the email, the user already have to autenticate him/herself when getting emails
b) set up a webpage with patient based authentication

Comment: If you want to encrypt the attachment, use existing software like WinZip, but any other solution would be more complicated by avoiding doing it right and encrypting the email itself

Comment: You just open the archive.  Winzip handles the encryption.  I didn't say it was a good idea, but the alternatives, are more complicated the email encryption implementations

Comment: It's extremely likely, if your doctor friend sends patient files by email unless the ENTIRE email is encrypted or will violate HIPAA.  The proper way, host the encrypted files, behind an account system, that only allows the patients to access the account.  Sending a patient their test results to a google mail account is a horrible idea

Comment: If you think the recipients will be unable to unzip or decrypt an attachment, then you're basically SOL when it comes to email.  If the doctor doesn't trust email, then don't use email; use a web server, reports in PDF, and logins for the patients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Windows *Office*, *LibreOffice* and other office suites offer a *Save as..* dialog with *Password* as an option. Save the message as a document with password and attach to the email.

[image: Writer Save As dlg]
[image: Writer Password dlg]

MS *Office/Open Office/LibreOffice* DOCX all use *[Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386986(v=vs.85).aspx)* (rather than the more-secure [Microsoft AES Cryptographic Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386979(v=vs.85).aspx)), which provides RSA and triple-DES encryption, but **not** AES-256 or greater. Thus, DOCX encryption is of only moderate strength, and **may or may not be HIPAA compliant**.

2. Compression applications such as 7-Zip and PeaZip offer encryption strength up to **AES-256**, and can encrypt and compress multiple documents at once, e.g. x-ray TIFF, OV summary DOC etc. This is more secure and also more efficient than using each application's encryption. It is simpler for the recipient, too, who would need to input just one password to open all files in the archive. It has been my experience that the various Zip tools are compatible, as well, even across OS -- for example, *7-Zip* files encrypted under Windows OS can be opened in Ubuntu's *archive manager*.

[image: 7-Zip encryption dlg]

As you state, the password should be given through a medium other than email, e.g. fax or phone. Best might be to call the recipient *after* the email is received and stay on the phone to talk through the decryption process.

Comment: Are the Windows Office and LibreOffice compatible, and would they also work with Apple's equivalent?  Not everyone has 7-Zip, etc, which might make this difficult, but I think it is a good option.

Comment: LibreOffice can save files in DOC and DOCX formats, so would be compatible. The various Zip tools encryption also seem to be compatible, as well, from my own observations, even across OS -- for example, 7-Zip files encrypted under Windows OS can be opened in Ubuntu's archive manager.

Comment: Its trivial to brute force a Word document password.   You have to be sure the document is actually encrypted if your not using Office to encrypt the document

Comment: Not true for DOCX format, which is PKZIP format and encrypted. Perhaps true for ancient DOC format. Take a look at the same DOCX files saved unencrypted vs. encryoted.